Not able to configure inlay hints for neovim v10
I am currently using neovim nightly and though I am getting InlayHints for rust it is only parameter types I am not getting lifetime elision hints on trying to change the configuration I saw on the rust_analyzer docs..
I have tried multiple approaches like using setup_handlers of mason-lspconfig.
Trying to setup the lsp outside of the mason-lspconfig.
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('LspAttach', {
    group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('user_lsp_attach', { clear = true }),
    callback = function(event)
        local opts = { buffer = event.buf }

        vim.keymap.set("n", '<C-i>', function() vim.lsp.inlay_hint.enable(0, not vim.lsp.inlay_hint.is_enabled(0)) end,
            opts)
    end,
})


local lsp_capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities()

require('mason').setup({})
require('mason-lspconfig').setup({
    ensure_installed = { 'tsserver', 'rust_analyzer', 'clangd' },
    handlers = {
        function(server_name)
            require('lspconfig')[server_name].setup({
                capabilities = lsp_capabilities,
            })
        end,
        rust_analyzer = function()
            require('lspconfig').rust_analyzer.setup({
                capabilities = lsp_capabilities,
                settings = {
                    ['rust_analyzer'] = {
                        inlayHints = {
                                lifetimeElisionHints = {
                                    enable = "always",
                                    useParameterNames = true
                                }

                        },
                    }
                }
            })
        end
   }
})




Try to add vim.lsp.inlay_hint.enable in the on_attach method like here;
local lspconfig = require 'lspconfig'

lspconfig.rust_analyzer.setup({
  filetypes = {"rust"},
  on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
    vim.lsp.inlay_hint.enable(true, { bufnr = bufnr })
  end,
  settings = {
    ['rust_analyzer'] = {
      cargo = {
        allFeatures = true
      },
      checkOnSave = {
        command = "clippy"
      },
    },
  },
})

Upd: source. You need neovim version 0.10 or later for this.

Also some LSP servesr requires additional config to have inlay hint turned on. Be sure to check the LSP server documentation.

It started working fine for me, I disabled/commented Mason rust_analyzer, added new plugin , below is my init.lua (lazy)

Focus on


vim.lsp.inlay_hint.enable(true)

{
  'mrcjkb/rustaceanvim',
  version = '^4', -- Recommended
  lazy = false, -- This plugin is already lazy
  config = function()
      vim.g.rustaceanvim = {
      -- Plugin configuration
      tools = {
      },
      -- LSP configuration
      server = {
        on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
          vim.lsp.inlay_hint.enable(true)
        end,
        default_settings = {
          -- rust-analyzer language server configuration
          ['rust-analyzer'] = {
          },
        },
      },
      -- DAP configuration
      dap = {
      },
    }
    end,
  },

